# Как избежать дублирования и пропуска сообщений для онлайн сервиса с вебсокетами

Tags: websocket, архитектура, проектирование, синхронизация

**Задача:**
Стоит задача написать сервис с онлайн чатом, уведомлениями и прочими оповещениями. Работать это должно через вебсокеты.

**Логика работы:** Пользователь создаёт соединение и отправляет серверу определённый запрос, который говорит о том, что теперь ему нужно отправлять все уведомления через этот вебсокет. Старые уведомления получаются через api.

**Реализация на сервере:** Как загружаются старые сообщения я думаю понятно, просто делается запрос к базе. Как обстоят дела с новыми: после создания такого сообщения оно попадает в некий `store`, в котором запущен бесконечный цикл с бесконечной проверкой данных этого `store`. Когда функция в бесконечном цикле видит, что там появилось новое сообщение/уведомление, то она рассылает это пользователям, которым оно адресовано и удаляет из `store`. При горизонтальном масштабировании этот `store` уезжает в отдельное приложение на отдельный сервер.

**Проблема:** Некоторые сообщения или уведомления могут потеряться/продублироваться. Допустим мы соединились с сервисом уведомлений и он нам их отправляет. Но прежде чем принимать такие уведомления мы должны загрузить старые, сделав запрос к базе. И тут пошли варианты:

1. Сначала загружаем уведомления из api, потом подключаемся к сервису уведомлений. Не будет работать - пока нам летит ответ от api может появиться новое сообщение и мы о нём никак не узнаем, потому что ещё не подключились к сервису уведомлений.
2. Окей, сначала подключаемся к сервису уведомлений, потом делаем запрос к api. Пока api обрабатывало наш запрос нам прилетело 3 уведомления. Далее приходит ответ от api. И как эти уведомления разбирать? Я конечно могу посмотреть по idшинкам, удалить одинаковые idшники, другие вставить в конец. Но это похоже на какой-то велосипед. Хотелось бы более лаконичного решения
3. Сделать 1 обработчик и для уведомлений и для загрузки старых? Без проблем! Но теперь та же проблема, только на стороне сервера, потому что пока я получаю данные из БД может сделаться `insert` нового сообщения. И оно не взялось. У меня конечно появляются в голове велосипеды со всякими вариантами синхронизации всего этого дела, но это так сложно и ненадёжно, что я их сразу откидываю
4. Обрабатывать это всё в 1 потоке я не буду, потому что это не масштабируется и упирается в производительность 1 ядра 1 сервера.
5. Создать в базе графу sended и проверять каждый раз отправку долбя базу в сервисе уведомлений? Нет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна надежная доставка, то тут нет уж очень простого решения. Есть более-менее приемлимые. Так же выбор зависит от некоторых дополнительных условий.

Вариант 2, который вы описали, возможно, самый простой. Особенно, если у вас клиент хранит состояние, что именно уже прочитано, какие уведомления пользователь видел и т.д. Ведь все равно уже придется это состояние поддерживать как-то и синхронизировать с тем, что пришло с сервера, как минимум будет логика первого вызова к api, которая будет учитывать, что уже загружено чтобы не получать дубликаты (или явно их игнорировать после получения). В этом случае устранить дубликаты, полученные в уведомлениях, не представляет сложностей. Нужно, конечно, дождаться выполнения запроса к api перед тем, как показывать пришедшие к этом моменту уведомления.

Вариант 1 может сработать неплохо, если у вас есть глобальный порядок всех сообщений и уведомлений в рамках одного пользователя. Т.е. если после получения ответа от api, при подписке на уведомления вы передадите идентификатор (который нужен для того чтобы достать порядковый номер или метку времени) самого нового сообщения полученного через api. Тогда сервис нотификации перед тем как посылать клиенту текущие доступные сообщения, сначала достанет все пропущенные сообщения из БД, пошлет их клиенту в первую очередь, а уже после этого пошлет текущие сообщения из `store`.

Сделать глобальный порядок для сообщений пользователя можно (небольшой) ценой сериализации создания сообщений для одного пользователя (т.е для одного пользователя нельзя вставлять два сообщения в БД параллельно), но при этом нет необходимости всю обработку делать в одном потоке.